Maven repository lookup order - always try central first
I need to use artifacts from a third-party repo in my project.
Therefore, I add the following to my POM:
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>bunch-of-cowboys</id>
        <name></name>
        <url>https://maven.bunch-of-cowboys.com</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

The problem I have is that I do not particularly trust this company that much. When I add the above, Maven will search bunch-of-cowboys before it searches central. This is by design. Effectively this company can now totally override anything in Maven Central .. and I probably wouldn't even find out if they did.
For me, this is a massive security risk. The other problem is that it prolongs builds. It might even prolong it significantly if that third-party Maven server is slow to respond.
I do understand that I can "fix" the problem by explicitly declaring Maven Central in my POM, for example:
<repositories>
    <!-- first, Maven Central -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <!-- then, Bunch of Cowboys -->
    <repository>
        <id>bunch-of-cowboys</id>
        <name></name>
        <url>https://maven.bunch-of-cowboys.com</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

It is not feasible to remember to do this in every project. It is also not feasible to educate all developers in my company to always remember to do this.
Therefore: How do people cope with this risk?  Is there a global switch in Maven which says to always prioritize central ? Frankly, I don't understand why the repository defined in the Maven Super POM (aka the central) do not take priority over any other defined repos.
Ref:  Maven official documentation on repo lookup order

On the one hand: it's weird that this option doesn't exist, on the other hand: if you don't trust them enough to be the source of random artifacts, how do you trust that they don't include malicious stuff in the artifacts you do get from them? If you find no other workaround, then you might want to set up a selective mirror of that repo on your infrastructure and just use that (maybe even with manual approval of individual artifacts for added security).

You can define a pom with exactly this setting that all your projects inherit from (=use it as parent).

"I don't understand why the repository defined in the Maven Super POM (aka the central) do not take priority over any other defined repos." because a) other people may have other needs, b) it is a design decision of the Maven developer (debating about such decisions is off topic here).

@f1sh: No, you suggestion would not solve the problem. Unless all projects have a need for bunch-of-cowboys  which they don't. Projects have different needs for different third-party repos. See the provided link for the order in which Maven will ask the defined repositories.

@JoachimSauer: True. My question was also to validate my understanding. From my understanding other build systems for other ecosystems have ways to "pin" a requested artifact to a specific source (Nuget, I think can do this with Package Source Mapping). Is there a similar feature available in Maven?

One way to cope with this is to set up an Artifactory server in your company.
You usually need something like this anyway to store the artifacts you built yourself.
Then you use that Artifactory as mirror of everything and add the repositories in Artifactory. There, you have fine-grained control, not only about the order of the repositories, but you could also restrict certain repositories to certain directories or (sub-)groupIds.

Still, if a single project within the organization need to obtain artifacts from say bunch-of-cowboys external repository then you would either (A) convince your Artifactory admin to add it globally (i.e. for everyone!) or (B) add it solely to POM of the project that specifically needs it .. bringing you back to the inherent problems stated in the original question. But yes, your solution is good if the organization can somehow agree on which external repos are needed. Kudos.

@peterh Not quite. Artifactory lets you define different virtual repositories (repository groups), so you could define one virtual repository general for everyone, and an additional one cowboy for the cowboy users. You could even use different credentials for them.
